# How does visual studio online generates commutative flow chart?

Tags: charts, tfs, azure-devops, kanban

I am interested in how visual studio online calculates commutative flow chart showing top of kanban board (like picture below )
[Commutative flow chart of work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTBHG.png)

I noticed the chart is updated daily at specific time. (may be it takes daily snapshot to generate chart data).

I have similar requirement to generate chart using azure sql server (with reporting service if required)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cumulative Flow Diagram (CFD) provides typical information about status of your project: how much work is done, ongoing and in backlog.

The chart will be automatically generated as the project goes. You can **Configure the CFD chart** accordingly based on your requirement and **Configure the CFD widget**, then **Add the widget to a dashboard**, then you can see the chart in dashboard. Other report server is not needed. See [**Cumulative flow**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/guidance/cumulative-flow) for details.

You can also create the CFD in excel, please reference this article [How to create a Cumulative Flow Diagram in Excel](https://hakanforss.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/how-to-create-a-cumulative-flow-diagram-in-excel-and-tfs-2010/)